# Shows the results of file selection (I use the file_picker plugin) before uploading onFlutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, file, dart, filepicker

Shows the results of file selection (I use the file_picker plugin) before uploading.

like we choose a PDF file to be sent on gmail automatically there is a special block of PDF attachments

after selecting the file the file will appear

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Mdp.jpg)

Comment: could you edit the question and be more specific about the issue?

Comment: file attachment use file picker.